# Clojure - oauth credentials and signature

Tags: oauth, clojure, flickr

Iam trying to implement oauth (clj-oauth https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth) for use with the flickr API.

I already have the access-token and just need the credentials but here I get stuck.

My code looks like this:

```
(def credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                    (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                    (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                    :GET
                                    "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/..."
                                    {:status "??")))
```

The url I need to call is:

```
 http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=3c2cfaf22751d55db9e0a4d02be254d7&user_id=92219076%40N07&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72987632743515342-8c99972fdac0b886&api_sig=cca1c874268986779d229f72ab65ee5a
```

But the example above is not clear for me and what is this :status?
Will the :status be translated to /?status="..." ?

And the second question is... where can I find the api_sig?
Should it be generated by oauth/make-consumer ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I read that oauth/credentials will build the base string and sign it. But I still dont understand the :status key...

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19058500/683965) to a similar question.

`api_sig` is part of Flickr's old, now deprecated non-oauth authentication.