# clojure oauth and credentials

Tags: oauth, clojure, flickr

I need some help with [clojure and oauth](https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth).

I got stuck at the last step: signing the request with the credentials.

```
(def credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                    (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                    (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                    :POST
                                    "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json"
                                    {:status "posting from #clojure with #oauth"}))

(http/put "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json" 
           :query-params credentials)
```

Thats the example from github.

Now, from the flickr API I have this test-url:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos
&api_key=82d4d4ac421a5a22et4b49a04332c3ff
&user_id=93029506%40N07&format=json&nojsoncallback=1
&auth_token=72153452760816580-cd1e8e4ea15733c3
&api_sig=b775474e44e403a79ec2a58d771e2022
```

I dont use twitter... I use the flickr api and want to GET the pictures of a user.

My question is now: How do I have to change the credentials that it fits the flickr url?
I am also confused about the `:status` but when I delete it I get an error...

Comment: is that api_key supposed to be secret? 82d4...?

Comment: Its just a testkey and will expire in a couple of hours... but I changed the numbers now... maybe safer ;)

Comment: It would be helpful if you give your real code (sans keys) rather then the twitter example.

Comment: FWIW, here is a repository that also uses this library (also twitter though): https://github.com/borkdude/whosnotfollowingme

Comment: Hey, I know you said that you would like to use a solution using clj-oauth, and Flickr uses OAuth 1 but I just wrote an entry about using the LinkedIn API (OAuth 2) without any oauth framework and I believe it might be useful (just in case, the whole OAuth and a query in 104 lines of Clojure). Link: http://malagastockholm.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/clojure-and-linkedin-api/ and repo: https://github.com/kikofernandez/clojure-linkedin

Answer (score 3):

The Twitter example uses the HTTP POST method, but for Flickr we want GET and the flickr api. So we do

```
(def credentials (oauth/credentials consumer
                                (:oauth_token access-token-response)
                                (:oauth_token_secret access-token-response)
                                :GET
                                "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
                                query-params))
```

In the twitter example, what I replaced with `query-params` specifies what get posted. It 
is a map that will be url-encoded into something like  `status=posting%20from%20%23clojure%20with%20%23oauth`. Conversely, the request from the API you mention has the following map for the non-oauth query-params:

```
(def query-params {:method "flickr.people.getPhotos" :format "json" :user_id "93029506@N07" :nojsoncallback 1})
```

Now all we have to do is

```
(http/get "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/" {:query-params (merge credentials query-params)})
```