# Clojure OAuth & Flickr

Tags: oauth, clojure, flickr

Iam following these steps https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html to implement oauth in my clojure prog.

Everything is working fine to step 3 with the following code. (printlns are just for checking the return values)

```
(def consumer-key "0000")
(def consumer-secret "0000")

(def consumer (oauth.client/make-consumer consumer-key
            consumer-secret
            "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token"
            "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token"
            "http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize"
            :hmac-sha1))

(def request-token (oauth/request-token consumer "http://localhost:8080/authorize"))

(defn flickrauth []
         (def auth-url (oauth/user-approval-uri consumer
         (:oauth_token request-token)))
         (println (str auth-url "&perms=write")))
```

After typing the auth-url to my my browser can authorize the access with write permissions.

```
(defn get-access-token [oauth-token verifier]
         (println "CONSUMER: " consumer "REQ TOKEN: " oauth-token "verifier: " verifier)
```

In the following code i only got "oauth_problem=token_rejected, status 401". So i guess there is a problem with exchanging the request token for an access token...

```
(def access-token-response (oauth/access-token consumer
                           request-token
                           verifier))

(println "ACCESS TOKEN RESPONSE: " access-token-response)
```

Short summary...
I get a request token and verifier, but in access-token-response is another oauth_token used..and i don't know why.

Thanks for any help and hint!

Comment: According to http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html it is normal that you get a oauth_token in the access-token-response....  Where is it you get the 401? During API-accesses? Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19058500/683965 to a similar question